# Initialization of bean failed SpelEvaluationException: EL1012E: Cannot index into a null value in spring batch Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.data.migrator.nameWriter'

So we are fetching records from Data base and for this query we have 100000 records.
We fetch record from Data base using spring batch in chunk of 5 records .

Basically we are able to read process record fine but when it comes to write bean  itialization fails with belwo error

Here is the stack trace

Here is my writer configuration

Also some time i do not get this error but most of the time i get this error .
Not able to find the exact place where this error comes .

Please suggest

Comment: What is `transientJobExecutionContext`?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Its just a mapping `<util:map id="transientJobExecutionContext" key-type="java.lang.String" map-class="java.util.HashMap" value-type="java.util.HashMap"/>`

Comment: Are you sure `jobParameters['sourceRootGroupId']` is always not resolved as a `null` value? `p:sourceRootGroupId` is resolved as a not-null value?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci i can see only that in the code ..Let me check again.How can i confirm this ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `abc.efg.data.migrator.service.core.writer.NameItemWriter.setSourceRootGroupId` or inspect `transientJobExecutionContext` during program execution for null values

Comment: just adding a good practice - use $df{  - on property if you re not sure whether it will be null or not for example

Comment: @AshishShetkar sure i will give try now

Comment: Could you share the github?

Comment: @NghiaDo sorry can not share git hub because of compliance issue  ..I can share more details if required.I am facing this issue in CI environment and we can not debug also .

Comment: can you share this class - abc.efg.data.migrator.service.core.writer.NameItemWriter

Comment: @AshishShetkar let me check ..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I bet problem is in following expression:

`#{transientJobExecutionContext[jobParameters['sourceRootGroupId']]['nameIds']}`

Try to comment out other expressions and one by one find out which one is not working.
Also another way to do this would be create your own class and inject `jobParameters`, `jobExecutionContext` and others...

But please note - it should be a scoped bean to access those.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/step.html#step-scope